# Short form correctness

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, ellipsis, parallelism

Can it be said as follows:

> He just didn't understand or pretended not to.

in the meaning the he either didn't understand or pretended he didn't?

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? What meaning do you *want* to convey? Your exact phrasing is fairly unlikely, because ***just*** in *He just didn't understand* is an *intensifier* (as with alternatives such as ***simply*** or ***really***). And it's a little bit "odd" to follow such an emphatic assertion with ***or** [something different]*. A more natural phrasing (which may or may not be what you're trying to say) might be, for example, *Either he simply didn't understand, or he was pretending that he didn't [understand].*

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly natural as is, in AmE.  Yes, the omission of "understand" is idiomatic (... pretended not to understand).  In AmE, the  **just** there would be understood to mean, "it's as simple as that".

Comment: @FumbleFingers it was supposed to sound a bit ironic, that's why I used *just*.

Comment: @TRomano, olegst: The way I first read it, ***just*** was intended to only apply to *he didn't understand* - the implication being that he had absolutely *no* understanding (i.e. - not some "fuzzy" partial grasp, or whatever). So it seemed reasonable to clarify that sense with the minor rearrangement I suggested. If it was intended to apply to the entire *either/or* assertion, that could be unambiguously conveyed with, say, *It's just that he either didn't understand, or he pretended not to.* But I've no idea which of those two possible meanings might be seen as more "ironic" than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is valid and natural. However, notice that **just** here may mean two things:

1. It may be an intensifier. "*I tried to explain it to him but he just didn't understand*"
2. It may mean "*It is as simple as that*" and it may act as an excuse.

Whatever ironic sense you might have wished to imbue the sentence with isn't really there. You might want to look into omitting "*just*" for clarity, or rephrasing the first part to "**It's just that he didn't understand or pretended not to**" as Mr.TRomano suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with that sentence.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/55288)

Comment: @VarunKN I think it answers the question exactly, or is there some other question that I do not see?